# Storing user's data on external database on other server

Tags: database

First of all, i am a Python developer and I have no clue about the amazing WordPress. My question is: We have a site built and installed with WordPress, And now we want to use an external database that is in different server (VPS server), So every time a new user create an account this data will be stored in that server's database.
So is there any ideas or tutorials that could be helpful in my case? How it's done is it from the scripts of WP or is it from dashboard?

My wp-dashboard tells that am using ***WordPress version: 5.8.2***

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to multiple databases using the wpdb class, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/.

From there you can do something like this:

```
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select field from my_table");
```

I'm not sure about changing the structure off storing the users to a different database. You may want to copy the users tables to a different database to still make use of the WordPress backend. If you take away the tables then you may need to change all login and registration processes too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But how/where should i add these two lines? As i mentioned before i have no clue with wordpress.